# Motion and VLC together

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, webcam, surveillance

I'm using Motion http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome with a v4l2 webcam on /dev/video0 for motion detection.

I'd like to also use vlc for rtp streaming. Let's say, Motion detects a movement and then automatically starts vlc to stream a video via rtp.

The problem is that vlc can't capture images from the webcam while it's being used by Motion.

```
v4l2 demux error: cannot set input (Device or resource busy)
```

Is there a workaround, trick, solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember the details of how I got this working several years ago (don't have access to that system any longer), but I basically published a copy of the video stream using Motion. Then instead of connecting VLC directly to the camera, I connected it to the relayed stream that Motion was publishing.

Answer (score 0):

There is software that can "split" a webcam in to multiple virtual devices, so that multiple programs can use its video feed at once. [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/) comes to mind, but I'm sure there are free equivalents that don't watermark the video. Asus preinstalls a program called Asus Virtual Camera on many of their laptops that does this, I suspect it would also work on non-Asus hardware. [Softpedia has downloads](http://drivers.softpedia.com/downloadTag/Asus+Virtual+Camera).